# Error while generating apex classes using Metadata WSDL

Tags: apex, metadata

I tried using the already generated and modified metadata service class (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls)
This works for me, But in order to deploy the class, I am getting a few PMD errors. To resolve the PMD errors(Class Naming Convention), I would like to rename the class names
Example :-I would like to change class name readCustomFieldResponse_element to ReadCustomFieldResponseElement

If I try changing the class name, I get this error - Got an unexpected error in callout: The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: Class: MetaDataService.readCustomFieldResponse_element

Can someone help
Can we change the class names? If yes, then what is the correct approach. If not, what’s the other suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL-generated files should not be modified unless you know what you're doing, as SOAP is XML-based and therefore case-sensitive. Use `@SuppressWarnings('PMD')` in the file to ignore all PMD warnings in the file.

Comment: We are not allowed to use @SuppressWarnings('PMD'). I am trying to generate Metadata classes using the standard Generate Metadata WSDL from Salesforce, but I am getting errors. Do you have documentation which provides a step by step process to generate Metadata class.